# How to convert word to pdf in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a question that maybe it's a little bit ridiculous. I want to produce an equipment in my ASP.Net project that the user can convert word documents to PDF. Is there any solution programmatically?

Or isn't there any code sample?

Comment: ohh..I see!! @Partow sorry guy. I have removed my Comment.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has capilities to do that. See [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/), the Document Server.

Answer (score 0):

Converting Word documents to PDF is a little bit tricky. What I've done in the past is invested in a third-party solution ([ActivePDF](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/docconverter/Overview.cfm?CFID=6403860&CFTOKEN=68839519&jsessionid=96301479491334428681797)) and wrote a service around it that could be consumed by applications that needed document conversion facilities.

Answer (score 0):

To create PDF from Word documents (DOC and DOCX) you will need to use a library (all commercial since I don't know of any free libraries dealing with DOC/DOCX and PDF):

- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)
- [Gembox.Documents](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview)

BTW:

There are several libraries (free and commercial) to deal with Office files (without Office Interop).

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 (which can't create PDFs!) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (newer formats only like DOCX, XLSX etc.).

Using Office interop in a server-scenario (like ASP.NET, Windows Service etc.) is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Additionally there have been several security-related changed since Windows Vista which basically make it really hard to do anything "desktop-like" in a Windows Service (IIS/ASP.NET is just a special case of Windows Service in this regard).